# Copy array formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel table:

```
          A                 B                    C                    D                       E
1                     Purchase Price        Sales Price      Purchase Price > Sales Price
2     Product A            50                    40        ={COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B10),IF(B2:B10>C2:C10-10,B2:B10)))}
3     Product B            60                    65
4     Product C            80                    60
5     Product D            10                    20
6     Product E            50                    30
7
```

Now I want use the following Macro to copy the formulas from cell B2:D6 into cell E2:G6:

```
Sub Array_Formula()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:G6").Formula = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D6").Formula
End Sub
```

This macro copies the formulas from cell B2:D6 into cell E2:G6. However, it does not copy the { } of the formula in cell D2 so it does not stay as an array.

How do I have to change my macro so it copies the formula including the array?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try instead of `.Formula` use `.FormulaArray`

Comment: Hi Scott, it does work with FormulaArray but only if I copy cell D2 seperately. Not if I want to copy the whole selection from B2 til D6.

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D6").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:G6").pastespecial xlformulas

Comment: Those were two lines of code...

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly.

Comment: The problem with using the copy/paste option: it's slower than reading to an array and then writing the array, like you can do for values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in the comments the solution is the following VBA:

```
Sub Copy_Array_Formula()
Sheet1.Range("B2:D6").Copy
Sheet1.Range("E2:G6").PasteSpecial xlFormulas
End Sub
```